# ionic4 display a dynamically created pdf file within inappbrowser

Tags: pdf, ionic-framework, ionic4, inappbrowser

I am new to ionic v4 and I have developed an app that has inappbrowser. On one page, a user fills in some data into input boxes and submits to another page action.php which uses fpdf library to generate a pdf and display it on the browser.

This works perfectly outside the app; but my problem is when i want the user to get the pdf within inappbrowser; on clicking the submit button, nothing happens.

Part of my code in the page generating pdf with fpdf library

```
require_once('libs/fpdf.php');
...
$pecno = $_POST['Pec_No']; 
...
$paperTypeA='Peg_Plan';

$ext='.pdf';

$paperNameA= $pecno.$paperTypeA.$ext;
$pdf->Output($paperNameA, "I" );
```

Comment: You have to make REST API. send your data via AJAX request and get PDF url and open it in inappbrowser

Comment: I do to know whether the REST API you talk about is what I have done so far; this is what I am using: subsclesoUrl(url: string) {
    //this.inappBrowser.create('http://example.comL/server_api/connect.html',"_self","location=no");
    this.inappBrowser.create(
      "http://example.com/pln3/lesoplanreg.php",
      "_blank",
      "location=yes"